# Minecraft server connection times out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

When someone tries to connect my server he gets "connection times out".
I know this question was asked a lot, but any other solution didn't help for me. 
So the common problem is that the port is blocked so I've tried this.
[image: port fowerding]

My server.properties is:

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Tue Nov 04 21:09:39 IST 2014
spawn-protection=16
max-tick-time=60000
generator-settings=
force-gamemode=false
allow-nether=true
gamemode=0
enable-query=false
player-idle-timeout=0
difficulty=1
spawn-monsters=false
op-permission-level=4
resource-pack-hash=
announce-player-achievements=true
pvp=true
snooper-enabled=true
level-type=DEFAULT
hardcore=false
Minecraft=server properties
enable-command-block=true
max-players=20
network-compression-threshold=256
max-world-size=29999984
server-port=25565
texture-pack=
server-ip=
spawn-npcs=true
allow-flight=false
level-name=world
view-distance=10
resource-pack=
spawn-animals=true
white-list=false
generate-structures=true
online-mode=true
max-build-height=256
level-seed=
enable-rcon=false
motd=A Minecraft Server
```

Comment: Need more information to help. What have you tried already? Any more details to the "Connection timed out" message? Does everyone get the timed out message or just one? Check your router to ensure you have port forwarding set up correctly. Make sure you have the latest version of Essentials.

Comment: i have done port flowering in the router (the first part of the image above ) .

Comment: i didn't install craftbukkit so i don't have essentials

Comment: and i checked just with one person this thing so i can't say about everyone ..

Comment: Search the web for "port forward check" and make sure your port can be accessed from outside your network - or head to the nearest library/café and hook up to wi-fi to try for yourself. You may need to also ensure you have OUTBOUND connections configured through port 25565.

Comment: i did it ,and it's returns also connection timed out .

Comment: and i set up the out bound rule i gonna restart my computer now

Comment: nope dosent work

Comment: Could you give me the Console log?

Comment: `[22:33:17] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[22:33:17] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[22:33:17] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[22:33:17] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[22:33:17] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "world"
[22:33:17] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[22:33:18] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 77%
[22:33:19] [Server thread/INFO]: Done (1.349s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
`